# htaccess with parameters to an subfolder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I searched for a solution to redirect from this URL:

```
www.domain.de/buynow.html?utm_source=test.de&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=demo
```

to this

```
www.domain.de/shop/buynow.html?utm_source=test.de&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=demo
```

Just for that one file should a rule generated. I Google a bit, but can’t find the solution I need with parameters that redirect all post/gets etc to /shop/file...

Any ideas? thanks!

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658268/htaccess-301-redirect-for-url-with-parameter) but it didn't work for my problem.

Comment: answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864507/htaccess-url-rewrite-to-subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest way that I know of.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^buynow.html /shop/buynow.html [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Here's what the different parts of the rewrite rule mean:

`^buynow.html` - the request starts with buynow.html

`/shop/buynow.html` - the destination

`[L,R=301,QSA]` - permanently redirect to the new location (R=301), pass the query string to the new location (QSA), and stop processing rewrite rules (L)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+buynow\.html\? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /shop/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: looks good, but all behind buynow.html? are parameters that are not static, they are dynamic and alltime different