# htaccess redirect 301 renamed file with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, parameters

I should rename a file (web page) with parameters and redirect *all* (parameters generated) old pages to newer like:

page.php -> renamed -> newpage.php

Redirect

```
page.php?param1=1&param2=string -> Redirect 301 -> newpage.php?param1=1&param2=string 
page.php?param1=2&param2=string -> Redirect 301 -> newpage.php?param1=2&param2=string 
page.php?param1=3&param2=string -> Redirect 301 -> newpage.php?param1=3&param2=string
```

...
...

What is the right .htaccess code ?

Thank you
M.

Comment: Maybe this question same with this problem, [try this answer][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658268/htaccess-301-redirect-for-url-with-parameter/20658952#20658952

Answer (score 0):

You can just place this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page\.php$ /newpage.php
```