# How to 301 redirect URLs like "/index.php/page" to new ones in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i replaced an old Joomla! Site with a new one and want to redirect selected old URLs to their appropriate new ones. The **old** Joomla! Site uses URLs like `example.com/index.php/news` or `example.com/index.php/about` and the new Site uses URLs like `example.com/latest-news.html` or `example.com/about-us.html`. Simple redirects using `RedirectPermanent` in .htaccess does not work (probably because the part after the slash is a query string, no URL segment). I searched the web but didn't found an answer.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "probably because the part after the slash is a query string" - What you've shown in your question is not a query string, that is additional _path information_ and is normally considered part of the URL path. Please include what you have already tried in your question. Also, add your existing `.htaccess` file, since there is quite probably a conflict with existing directives.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/news http://example.com/latest-news.html
```

For query strings, did you look at similar post [htaccess 301 redirect for URL with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658268/htaccess-301-redirect-for-url-with-parameter?rq=1)

Comment: If you specify the domain in the target URL then you'll need to make it an absolute URL with scheme. (Or use a root-relative path)

Comment: Oh yes! I tried this before without success but now it is working. And so simple. Thank you very much!